# Fragment Layout components are null

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, drawerlayout

I have created a DrawerLayout(containing a NavView for a menu) fragment and named it NavMenuFragment and i've tried implementing it into my mainActivity.java class without succession. After running the debugger i noticed that all of the layouts from the fragment's layout file do not get initialized thus equaling to null. Any ideas on why this is happening? Here are the .java class and the .xml file from the fragment :

Fragment.java:

public class NavMenuFragment extends Fragment {

```
// NavMenu member vars
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private NavigationView navigationView;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle; // Button for toggling the side menu

// Keeps the position of the previously selected menu item(0 : Home)
int position = 0;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nav_menu,null);
    mDrawerLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    navigationView = view.findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(),mDrawerLayout,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_closed); // Instantiating our button

    // Sets the default selected menu item, to the Home item
    navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_home).setChecked(true);

    // Used to help on check and uncheck menu items when the user clicks on them
    final List<MenuItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
    Menu menu;
    menu = navigationView.getMenu();

    // Fill the list with all the menu items
    for(int i=0; i<menu.size();i++) {
        items.add(menu.getItem(i));
    }

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "size:" + items.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // When an item inside the NavView gets clicked, then handle the event...
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_UserBoxGLB:
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_UserBoxJP:
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_settings:
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_feedback:
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_contact_us:
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_donate:
                    // Open the website's URL in a browser window
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_about:
                    break;
                default:
                    return onNavigationItemSelected(item);
            }
            items.get(position).setChecked(false);
            item.setChecked(true);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            return false;
        }
    });

    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    // Set the hamburger icon's color
    mToggle.getDrawerArrowDrawable().setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.NavActionBarTextColor));
    mToggle.syncState();
}

// When an item from the Action Bar gets tapped, then...
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item) || onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

fragment.xml:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout">

    <!-- The actual side menu Nav View -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: You should use the View parameter, not `getView()`

Comment: By the way, FrameLayout is not necessary. A DrawerLayout is a top-level view

Comment: @cricket_007 thank you for both tips.  Sadly, after implementing both of them and debugging the app, still every view from the fragment's layout is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **RETURN** VIEW
- Pass **VIEW** Object instead of **getView()**.
- **`FrameLayout`**- No need.

Try this way

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nav_menu, null);
        mDrawerLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
         ..................................
        navigationView = view.findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        return view;
}
```

Comment: i tried doing this but still all of my views are null when it comes to this fragment. I also implemented the changes suggested in the comments above but nothing changed. Would changing this line have any positive effects?  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nav_menu,container); ?

Comment: @SteliosPapamichael did you call all views `view.findViewById` ?

Comment: @SteliosPapamichael remove `FrameLayout` from xml and code.

Comment: i'm not too sure, here is what i tried but ended up crashing the app. Transferred all of the code inside onViewCreated into onCreateView and just changed the getView() part with view where necessary. Should i only transfer the views and leave the rest of the code back there? And yeah i did remove the FrameLayout. :D

Comment: @SteliosPapamichael `Should i only transfer the views and leave the rest of the code back there?` yes, You can do. By the by show logcat(error)

Comment: Never mind the app crash. I did something stupid. Now, i placed all the views inside the onCreateView() and left the rest of the code as is but still they are null for some reason. I'm updating the fragment.java class in my post